# Error with ArrayAdapter context in another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-context

The thing is ... In an Activity I fill some fields to popularem one ListView to be loaded into another Acitivity , has tried to show it in the same Activity and works, the error happens when I try to show it in another Acitivity , I believe It has to do with the Context.

The Activity used to populate the parameters and that works if the list is shown it is called FiltrarImoveis where this step only in the Context of ArrayAdapter .

The Activity giving problem is called DetalhesImoveis , try to pass this , DetalhesImoveis.this and keeps giving error ... Here is the Activity section of code that is giving error:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> listaImoveis = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaImoveis.add("foo");
    listaImoveis.add("bar");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adpImovel = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DetalhesImoveis.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaImoveis);
    lvImoveis.setAdapter(adpImovel);
}
```

Full code DetalhesImoveis.class:

```
package com.example.dhjeferson.testemenu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetalhesImoveis extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvImoveis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> listaImoveis = new ArrayList<String>();
        /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhes_imoveis);
        TextView showParsedJSON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.json);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String output = intent.getStringExtra("output");
        showParsedJSON.setText(output);*/
        /*FiltrarImoveis filtrarImoveis = new FiltrarImoveis();
        listaImoveis = filtrarImoveis.retornaLista();*/
        lvImoveis = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvImoveis);

        Imovel imv = new Imovel();
        imv.setGenero("Genero");
        imv.setFinalidade("Finalidade");
        imv.setTipo("Tipo");
        imv.setValor("Valor");
        listaImoveis.add("foo");
        listaImoveis.add("bar");
        try {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adpImovel = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DetalhesImoveis.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaImoveis);

            lvImoveis.setAdapter(adpImovel);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v("logs","ERROR CAUSED BY THE EXCEPTION LIST: "+e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detalhes_imoveis, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error - compile time or runtime? Do you have any message with the error?

Comment: Because `Activity` indirectly extends `Context`, you can just pass along 'this' as a `context`- no need for `DetalhesImoveis.this`. If that doesn't fix it, could you please check your LogCat for an exception and post it here?

Comment: thank you, but I've tried that way and gives error as well. okay, I 'll do it .

Comment: Where is the `lvImoveis` defined? I think `lvImoveis` belongs to different activity and you are trying to use that ListView in `DetalhesImoveis` Activity.

Comment: It is set in a global context , in DetalhesImoveis class.

Comment: the exception error is the following: ERROR CAUSED BY THE EXCEPTION LIST: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4214d9a0

Comment: Please, see the code of DetalhesImoveis.

Comment: How do I get the error of exception? I am new to Java, can , please help me?

Comment: You have `setContentView` commented out so there is no layout to inflate your `ListView` from. This would give a `NullPointerException` when trying to set the `Adapter` on the `ListView`

Comment: [This explains how to get it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: un comment `setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhes_imoveis);`  and make sure `lvImoveis` is defined in `activity_detalhes_imoveis` layout.

Comment: And **never** try to instantiate an `Activity` like this `new FiltrarImoveis();`. Get the list through an `Intent`, DB, another class but not like that

Comment: Oooohh my God, you're right, I said not wanting to do other tests and forgot , thank you even !!